# Javascript Regular expression for image file to FileUpload control in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I am trying to verify image file which is choose by user in FileUpload control in web page at client side by using javascript.
Can anybody tell me how can i make it.
I am trying this code for that which is not working :

```
function validateFileExtension() 
{
    var re =/\.(gif|jpg|JPEG|tiff|png)$/i;
    var temp = document.getElementById('<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>').value;

    if (re.test(temp)) 
    {
        return ("Invalid image file type.");

        return false;
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: You can'y *really* verify file type by just checking the filename extension.

Comment: ... and you need `if (!re.test(temp))` because `.test()` returns `true` when the regex finds a match.

Comment: also you have two `return`'s in that condition..that `return false` will never execute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this its working for me...

```
    function validateImage() {
        var uploadcontrol = document.getElementById('<%=imgUploader.ClientID%>').value;
        //Regular Expression for fileupload control.
        var reg = /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.gif)$/;
        if (uploadcontrol.length > 0) {
            //Checks with the control value.
            if (reg.test(uploadcontrol)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                //If the condition not satisfied shows error message.
                alert("Only .jpg, .jpeg,.png, .gif  files are allowed!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    } //End of function validate.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private  final String IMAGE_PATTERN = "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)";
```